# Tween time based on distance

Tags: math, unity-game-engine, tween, lerp

I'm tweening several game objects (with LeanTween) and want the time to be shorter if the distance between distance points a and b are shorter. I used to write my own forumla for it years ago but forgot it (duh). Can somebody give me a hint? And is `Mathf.Lerp` (or similar) of any use here? If I use the following, it does exactly the opposite (time gets longer the shorter the distance, which is what I don't want) ..

```
float time = Mathf.Lerp(source.transform.position.y, target.transform.position.y, Time.time);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From docs http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Lerp.html

> public static float Lerp(float a, float b, float t);
>
> Linearly interpolates between a and b by t. The parameter t is clamped
>   to the range [0, 1].

So, `time` variable in your sample will be equal to `target.transform.position.y` in most cases because `Time.time` is increasing. That's why your time became longer.

Following code will give reduced time depended by traveled distance (`tweenObject` is a object controlled by LeanTween)

```
float time = Mathf.Lerp(tweenObject.transform.position.y, 
target.transform.position.y, 
source.transform.position.y / tweenObject.transform.position.y);
```

Comment: Great thanks! This is what I was looking for exactly!

Comment: One question though: tweenObject.transform.position and source.transform.position are initially the same. That would mean that this time value needs to be updated constantly during a tween?

Comment: Yes, you, probably, will need to update it inside of Update(), FixedUpdate() or another appropriate function

Answer (score 1):

If I get you right, what you want is a constant velocity, which makes your objects arrive faster when the distance is shorter.

```
float speed = 2f; // 2 units per second

void Update()
{
    Vector3 distance = targetPosition - transform.position;
    float distanceLen = distance.magnitude;

    float stepSize = Time.deltaTime * speed;

    if (stepSize > distanceLen)
        transform.position = targetPosition;
    else
    {
        Vector3 direction = distance.normalized;
        transform.position += direction * stepSize;
    }
}
```

Comment: This works Ok but uses Update for tweening. In my case I want to use a dedicated Tweener to use easing equations and other features.